# cURL not working on tag

Tags: php, html, css, curl

I have try to copy a sentence from a [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

my code is:

```
$request_url ='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);    // The url to get links from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the respone
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$regex='/<h1 itemprop="name">(.*)<\/h1>/i';
preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
$links=$parts[1];
foreach($links as $link){
    echo $link."<br>";
}
curl_close($ch);
```

It is worked, But when i try to change on line number 6 it doesn't work

```
$regex='/itemprop="name">(.*)<\/h1>/i';
```

Script of this website from which i want to copy is:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
<a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php">Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?</a></h1>
```

I want to print "Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?" Please tell me how i copy and print that sentence from this anchor tag.

Comment: The regex does not work anymore because your line-start/first characters are not covered in the regex. It should be `/^.*itemprop="name">(.*)<\/h1>/i`

Comment: @smoes No output. Blank page.

Comment: @smoes this code /^.*itemprop="name">(.*)<\/h1>/si is work but it doesnt print "Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?". Its print more then this sentence.

Comment: I posted an answer to that and will add you new question to the answer as well. Please accept the answer if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `DOMDocument` with `DOMXpath` too. Consider this example:

```
$request_url ='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url); // The url to get links from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the response
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// target the title
$title = $xpath->query('//div[@id="question-header"]/h1[@itemprop="name"]/a[@class="question-hyperlink"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title; // Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?
```

> Sidenote: This is the most odd scraping question, scraping SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your regex to parse the input as a one-liner. To be more exact you need to tell you regex to not match the newline, since the newline is not part of the `.`

This [can be done](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) by adding an *s* to the *i* at the end of the line:

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>   If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Your regex will look like:

```
/itemprop="name">(.*)<\/h1>/is
```

---

All you need to do to get the text inside the other tags is now to get rid of them too. At the moment you take the inner of the h1-tag. Be careful that you handle the newline before the a-tag:

```
/itemprop="name">.*<a.*>(.*)<\/a><\/h1>/is
```

will do the trick!